# Reading from file row by row and searching for text

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and I am currently trying to read from a text file "data.txt"

The text file contains data that looks like this :

Hello world, apple, balloon, POSITIVE

Shark, tiger, fruit, NEGATIVE

I would like to read from the file row by row and search for a word till the first delimiter ",". 
If a result is found, I will then return the entire row by writing that row into another .txt file called output.txt.

For example, if I search for the word "Hello" after the program is run, output.txt would contain Hello world, apple, balloon, POSITIVE

I have tried using buffered reader but I am unsure of how I can get it to work.

Here are my codes for the buffered reader initialization:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
    FileReader("D:\\Downloads\\dataAnalysis1.txt"));  
  String line;
  while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
  {
      System.out.println(line);
      // extract by lines and write to file 

  }
  in.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue, the code you have posted looks alright but I see no attempt to implement the logic you describe in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using below program. First part of your program (reading lines using `BufferedReader`) is correct.

I've used Java's try-with-resources feature (introduced in Java 7) here. It takes care of closing the files after reading/writing.

I've used `String.contains()` API to check whether the searched word exists in a line. Then I've used `BufferedWriter` to write matching lines to the output file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FindWord
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String searchWord = "Hello";

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("D:\\Downloads\\dataAnalysis1.txt"));
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
             new FileWriter("D:\\Downloads\\output.txt")))
    {
      String line;
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
      {
        System.out.println(line);

        // extract by lines and write to file
        String firstColumn =  line.split(",")[0];
        if (firstColumn.contains(searchWord))
        {
          out.write(line);
          out.newLine();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that javas modern IO framework NIO might come in handy here. `Files.lines(...).filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());` and then simply `Files.write(...)`.

Comment: Note that OP only wants to search in the first column (until the first comma). So you need to check `line.split(",")[0]` for `contains(searchWord)`.

Comment: @Zabuza, I understood as OP wants to search the whole line. I'll ask that in the question.

Comment: @Zabuza, I think you are correct. Now when I read the question again, I realize that OP only wants to search the first column. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Java 8 or higher, you can use **NIO** to do this. NIO is a modern IO framework which replaces the old `File`, `BufferedReader`, ... for many instances. It revolves around the classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`.

We will use `Files#lines` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path))) to stream-read all lines of your file, split a line by `,` and filter the first column by your search needle and then collect them into a list. Finally, we will write all remaining lines in the list to your file using `Files#write` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.file.OpenOption...))).

```
Path source = Paths.get("D:\\Downloads\\dataAnalysis1.txt");
Path destination = Paths.get("D:\\Downloads\\output.txt");

String needle = "Hello";

try {
    List<String> lines = Files.lines(source)
        .filter(line -> line.split(",")[0].contains(needle))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(destination, lines);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the problem
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```